# Given two arrays each containing n sorted elements, is there a O(log n)-time algorithm to find the medians of all 2n elements?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, selection-sort

**O(n) approach** is to **merge the two lists and then averaging** the middle two elements.
But can it be optimised further ? **Is there a O(log n) solution** to the problem?

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/

Comment: Thanks @PeterdeRivaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in O(log n)^2 time with a nested binary search. Your two guesses for the median and highest element and lowest element (which you can get in two comparisons). Then take the mid. Then find the indices of the mid with two binary searches. That tell you whether your estimate is too high or too low, and iterate the outer binary search.

Comment: Indeed it may be a solution, not meeting the demand though. Since the median has to lie between the two medians ! Cant single binary search (loop) be used?

Comment: That's a good idea for a speed up. But you still have to find the index of any proposed answer in the other array, which is O(log N).

Comment: O(log n) was very possible!!